# addition of distinct substrings of multiple strings to a Treeset

Tags: java, string, nullpointerexception, runtime-error, treeset

Question - You are given n strings w1, w2, ......, wn. Let Si denote the set of strings formed by considering all unique substrings of the string wi. A substring is defined as a contiguous sequence of one or more characters in the string. More information on substrings can be found here. Let S = {S1 U S2 U .... Sn} .i.e S is a set of strings formed by considering all the unique strings in all sets S1, S2, ..... Sn

My approach - I am using a TreeSet and filling it directly rather than creating a list, a set, and a sorted list.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution 
{

 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int cases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    String[] a = new String[cases];
    int i, c;

//Adding directly to the Set prevents a larger list because you remove the duplicates
Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();

   for( i = 0; i < cases; i++) 
    {
        a[i] = in.nextLine();
          for (c = 0; c < a[i].length(); c++) 
         {
            for (i = 1; i <= a[i].length() - c; i++) 
            {
                String sub = a[i].substring(c, c + i);
                set.add(sub);
            }
         }

     } 
  }
```

for input :

```
2
aab
aac
```

i got a runtime error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Solution.main(Solution.java:32)
```

can anyone explain me why i am getting this runtime error , what should i do to avoid this null pointer exception and why did this occur in the first place? please help me if you can

Comment: you might want to check what would happen for last iteration of `i`

Comment: for last iteration of i , value of i=a[i].length() - c , whats wrong with it? @singhakash

Comment: fort he first iteration of outermost loop you initialized `a[0]` but for the innermost loop you are accesing `a[1].length()` here `a[1]` is not initialized giving you null pointer.And why do you have nested loop with same varible name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a lot of memory nowadays. But even old days it was considered a bad practice to use the same variable for different purposes. Use each one for one purpose and it will be all right. Code is clear and undersatndable and no more unexplainable exceptions:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new StringReader("2\naab\naac\n"));

        int cases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
        String[] a = new String[cases];
        //int i, c;

        // Adding directly to the Set prevents a larger list because you remove
        // the duplicates
        Set<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < cases; i++) {
            a[i] = in.nextLine();
            for (int c = 0; c < a[i].length(); c++) {
                for (int ii = 1; ii <= a[i].length() - c; ii++) {
                    String sub = a[i].substring(c, c + ii);
                    set.add(sub);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

P.S. Homework - make name of variables meaningful and unforgetable.